# SSAS Cube Sync Takes Too Much Time

Tags: ssas, tabular, cube, ssas-tabular

When I try to sync in SSAS between two servers in same version. It stucks in "Backup Metadata Traversal Finished". Sync doesn't start. It takes 1.5 hours.

When I delete the cube in server and sync again, it takes 5 minutes. I checked the locks, sync step is showing lock type 4. What should I do?

Other cube in same server  sync progress takes 5-10 minutes. There is no problem in server.

Thank you.

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQIxs.png)

Answer (score 0):

We updated our analysis services version and problem solved.